# Is there any code I can use to make images appear the same on a mac as they do on a pc?

Tags: php, macos, css

I have coded a website for a client. It is responsive and works perfectly on most devices ex: IPad landscape and portrait as well as IPhone. The client is using a Macbook and is telling me that the images are skewed when viewing from his device, so my question is do I need to add something like

```
    @media only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

    }
}
```

here is the code for that particular area.

```
.DisplayAds_Grid { width: 100%; float: none; display: inline-block; margin-top: 20px; vertical-align: top;}
.DisplayAds_Grid .Banner_Wrapper { width: 18%; min-height: 178px; float: none; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; background-color: #fff; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 5px; text-align: center; border: 3px solid #dfdfdf; padding: 10px; }
```

to my media queries so that it looks the same on his device. I haven't had this problem before, so any help would be great. The site is http://www.verobeach.com and more specifically he is speaking about the featured businesses. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps ask the client to be more specific? I'm not sure what s/he is referring to in regards to "skewed".

Comment: Meaning the images seperate and drop below the other images and I can't understand why.

Comment: If they're on a Mac, they're probably running the Safari browser. Is any of your code incompatible with Safari? (For example, are you using some javscript library or something that is writing specific HTML for IE that is breaking on Safari?) This is all just conjecture because we can't see what your Mac user is seeing.